# Ruby, Getting a list count from a Param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my Rails 3 app, I have a form that posts XXX,XXXXXXXX What I want to be able to do is something like so:

```
params[:myfield].count
or 
params[:myfield].size
```

But that always returns 1, how can I get a count for the number of items by comma separation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
params[:myfield].split(",").size
```